# JQ: Delete duplicate entry inplace

Tags: jq

I am trying to delete a key whose value is duplicated elsewhere. That is I would like to delete all occurences(duplicates) after the first occurence. Here is a sample json file I am working with

```
{
   "clouds":{
      "finfolk-vmaas":{
         "auth-types":[
            "oauth1"
         ],
         "endpoint":"http://10.125.0.10:5240/MAAS/",
         "type":"maas"
      },
      "vsphere":{
         "auth-types":[
            "userpass"
         ],
         "endpoint":"10.247.0.3",
         "regions":{
            "QA":{
               "endpoint":"10.247.0.3"
            }
         },
         "type":"vsphere"
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to get this after the deletion:

```
{
   "clouds":{
      "finfolk-vmaas":{
         "auth-types":[
            "oauth1"
         ],
         "endpoint":"http://10.125.0.10:5240/MAAS/",
         "type":"maas"
      },
      "vsphere":{
         "auth-types":[
            "userpass"
         ],
         "endpoint":"10.247.0.3",
         "regions":{
            "QA":{}
         },
         "type":"vsphere"
      }
   }
}
```

Essentially I want to remove this duplicate key:pair `"endpoint":"10.247.0.3"` and leave the enclosing parentheses `{}`

Here is a simple jq query that I am trying to play with:
`jq -cs 'unique_by(.endpoint)' clouds.json`

Comment: What if its just `"endpoint":"http://10.125.0.10:5240/MAAS/",`? should it be set to empty string `""`? or removed altogether?

Comment: It should be left as is. Each object inside `clouds` is treated independently and there can only be one `endpoint` key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each object in `.clouds[]`, this saves the object reduced to its enpoint as `$endpoint`, then recursively traverses to all child objects, from which, if it `contains` the previously stored endpoint, (only) the endpoint field will be `del`eted.

```bash
.clouds[] |= ({endpoint} as $endpoint | .[] |= walk(
  (objects | select(contains($endpoint))) |= del(.endpoint)
))
```

```json
{
  "clouds": {
    "finfolk-vmaas": {
      "auth-types": [
        "oauth1"
      ],
      "endpoint": "http://10.125.0.10:5240/MAAS/",
      "type": "maas"
    },
    "vsphere": {
      "auth-types": [
        "userpass"
      ],
      "endpoint": "10.247.0.3",
      "regions": {
        "QA": {}
      },
      "type": "vsphere"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D2ldPPvyhvv)

Comment: This only deletes objects right? i.e. `{endpoint}`? It is not clear if e.g. say `"http://10.125.0.10:5240/MAAS/"` is duplicated

Comment: @Inian This only deletes fields called `endpoint` which contain the value of the stored endpoint's value. Other fields of such objects, and non-objects are left as-is. To be honest, I don't really understand what you may see duplicated.

Comment: Check https://jqplay.org/s/tTK4oxxjTGe

Comment: @Inian Okay, I see. My interpretation of the OP was firstly to only "remove" content, and secondly to treat each `.clouds[]` independently. (And also to treat containment as actual stringwise containment, i.e. delete `"endpoint":"http://10.247.0.3:5240/MAAS/"` in the second example.)

Comment: @pmf. Curious to know what if I wanted to also delete the top level enclosing key `clouds` and remain with such as results.
`{ "finfolk-vmaas": {"auth-types": ["oauth1"],"endpoint": "http://10.125.0.10:5240/MAAS/","type": "maas"},"vsphere": {"auth-types": ["userpass" ], "endpoint": "10.247.0.3","regions": {"QA": {}},"type": "vsphere" } }`

Comment: Found out how using the above answer. [DEMO](https://jqplay.org/s/geEOhEHwgdg)

Comment: @basebandit Is changing `.clouds[] |=` to `.clouds | .[] |=` the answer to your question? -- Ah, you have already found a way just using `.[] |=`. Btw, their difference is in how your input document is structured (or what code you embed this code into). It may or may not be necessary to prepend `.[] |=` with `.clouds |`.